# Does clickhouse stores ReplacingMergeTree tables data ordered by primary key?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE products ON CLUSTER cluster
(
    Id           UUID,
    Code         String,
    DownloadedAt DateTime,
    ...
    (~30 more columns)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (Id, Code)
PRIMARY KEY (Id, Code, DownloadedAt);
```

I expect the data to be updated based on item ID and code: if I insert a new product with the same ID and Code the existing product should be updated including DownloadedAt column.

But I also want products to be ordered by DownloadedAt like with clustered index.
As I see [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree) clickhouse stores data sorted by primary key in case of MergeTree, and ReplacingMergeTree differs from MergeTree in that it removes duplicate entries with the same sorting key value (from [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree)).

Is my table creation code satisfies both this conditions? Is it OK to create table like this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both the PRIMARY KEY and the ORDER BY entries - they are both essentially the same thing.

If you will be filtering on all of those columns, then use this ORDER BY statement:
ORDER BY (Id, Code, DownloadedAt);

However, note for ReplacingMergeTree, you can also define a version column. So if you have versioning in use in your data for the Id or Code columns, you may want to add the most recent time as a version to the ReplacingMergeTree definition also:
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree(DownloadedAt)

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree

Hope that helps - please let us know

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Thom. Thank you for your suggestion, that's the thing that I needed! And also I want to know the following: after deduplication I have a set of products all with different pairs (Id, Code). Can I have them stored in the way they sorted by DownloadedAt? I need to merge them by Id and Code, but I want to query products by date (e.g. products downloaded for the last 3 or 4 days).